# Getting a fimbriated plot

Tags: plotting, mathematica-online

I use the online version of Mathematica.

The function I want to plot is:

```
f[w_] := 
  Module[{M, Omega, normM, eigs},
    M = 
      Abs[{{(I*w+3)/((I*w+6)(I*w+1)), 1/(6*I*w+1)},
           {(I*w+1)/(-w^2+11*I*w+100), 2/(2*I*w+1)}}];   
    Omega = DiagonalMatrix[{M[[1,1]], M[[2,2]]}];
    normM = Dot[Inverse[Omega], M];
    eigs = Eigenvectors[normM];
    Return[eigs[1]]]
```

My plotting code is:

```
LogLinearPlot[f[w][[0, 1]], {w, 0.1, 1000}, 
  GridLines -> {Full, Automatic},
  GridLinesStyle -> Gray]
```

[image: The result is:]

The S-curves are true results. How to get rid of the tassels (fimbriae)?

Comment: Don’t use `Inverse`; it can lead to numerical instability. Instead, use `LinearSolve` to do the same, I.e. replace your definition of `normM` within $f$ with `normM = LinearSolve[Omega, M]`. That will fix your problem.

Answer (score 5):

First, I think your code should be corrected to;

```
f[w_] :=
  Module[{M, Omega, normM, eigs},
    M =
      Abs[
        {{(I*w + 3)/((I*w + 6) (I*w + 1)), 1/(6*I*w + 1)}, 
         {(I*w + 1)/(-w^2 + 11*I*w + 100), 2/(2*I*w + 1)}}];
    Omega = DiagonalMatrix[{M[[1, 1]], M[[2, 2]]}];
    normM = Dot[Inverse[Omega], M];
    eigs = Eigenvectors[normM];
    eigs[[All, 1]]]
```

Then evaluating `f` symbolically gives an expression that should plot smoothly.

```
f[w]
```

[image: expr]

Consequently, we should use `Evaluate` when plotting, like so:

```
LogLinearPlot[Evaluate @ f[w], {w, 0.1, 1000},
  PlotRange -> All,
  GridLines -> {Full, Automatic},
  GridLinesStyle -> {Gray, Directive[Gray, Thin]},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Instead of using `Evaluate`, you could define the function immediately with `f[w_] = Module[...]` and then plot it with `LogLinearPlot[f[w], ...]`. I believe that beginners' attention should be directed to the distinction between immediate and delayed definitions, and their respective uses.

Comment: Using `Set` change the definition to `f[w_] = Module[ ... ;
   eigs[[All, 1]] // ComplexExpand // 
    Simplify[#, Element[w, Reals]] &]`